# Android: Renderscript returning distorted image after HSV computation in script

Tags: android, renderscript

Hello all fellow geeks,

I am writing a view for HSV color wheel, and i am generating the HSV Color Wheel bitmap in renderscript. I am using the same algorithm in iOS and it is working well in iOS and Java, but in renderscript i am getting below pattern, looks distorted and unacceptable from end user perspective

Is this might be cause of floating point calculations, and the image i showing different distortion on different devices.

[image].

P.S I tried in java and it was taking around 4-5 secs on my moto-g, but in renderscript the process in taking like 600ms. (thats really fast!)

[image]

Comment: Rookie mistake ! since script is ran on multithreaded environment, so need to make sure about global members!

Comment: For best performance you want to avoid writing script globals as much as you can.  However, if you really need them RenderScript has atomic operations to make them safe.